# Documenting c functions in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, documentation

Is there a way to automatically provide a documentation template for a C function in emacs? For example, let's say I have this function:

```
const bool are_equal_int_float(const int a, const float b)
{
  bool result = false;

  // Do work

  return result;
}
```

I want to put the cursor somewhere inside the function and run a command that will parse the declaration and use it to create an explanation above the function. I would end up with something like this (it doesn't have to be the same format):

```
/* are_equal_int_float
 *
 * explanation: 
 *
 * params
 * a: 
 * b: 
 * 
 * returns: 
 */
const bool are_equal_int_float(const int a, const float b)
{
bool result = false;

// Do work

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote an emacs-lisp function called `jd-document-c-function-in-emacs`.

Once the emacs-lisp function is evaluated, just put the cursor anywhere inside the C function and type:

`M-x` `jd-document-c-function-in-emacs` `RET`

Note that my function works only in a buffer opened with some `C-mode`, since, in `fundamental` mode, for example, the function `beginning-of-defun` goes to the opening curve brace instead of the "real" beginning of the C function.

```
(defun jd-document-c-function-in-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (unless (beginning-of-defun)
        (error "Could not find %s" 'beginning-of-defun))
      ;; Narrow to <beginning of fun> <end of arg list>
      (narrow-to-region (point) (progn (forward-list) (point)))
      (let* ((bod     (point-min))
             (eolarg  (point-max))
             (bolarg  (progn (goto-char (point-max)) (backward-list) (point)))
             (bofname (progn (backward-sexp) (point)))
             (eofname (progn (forward-sexp)  (point)))
             (fname   (buffer-substring bofname eofname))
             (eoftype (progn
                        (goto-char bofname)
                        (backward-word)
                        (forward-word)
                        (min (point) bofname)))
             (ftype   (buffer-substring bod eoftype))
             (arg-re  (concat "[[:space:]]*"
                              "\\([^,)]*\\)"
                              "[[:space:]]+"
                              "\\([^[:space:]]+\\)"
                              "[,)]"))
             (largt   (list))
             (largn   (list))
             (dformat (concat "/* %s\n" " *\n" " * explanation:\n" " *\n"
                              " * params\n"))
             (aformat (concat " * %s:" " (%s)" "\n"))
             (rformat (concat " *\n" " * returns:" " (%s)" "\n" " */\n"))
             )
        (goto-char bolarg)
        (forward-char)                  ; skip lpar
        (while (re-search-forward arg-re eolarg 'noerror)
          (let ((argt (buffer-substring (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
                (argn (buffer-substring (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2))))
            (setq largt (nconc largt (list argt)))
            (setq largn (nconc largn (list argn)))))
        (goto-char bod)
        (insert (format dformat fname))
        (cl-mapc (lambda (argn argt) (insert (format aformat argn argt)))
                 largn largt)
        (insert (format rformat (if (string-blank-p ftype) "void" ftype)))))))
```

HTH

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'm slowly picking up elisp but it will be a while before I can really make it do what I want